# MySQL data type discrepancy after database migration

Tags: php

I'm facing an issue with my Flutter app's API responses after migrating my MySQL database to a new server on Hostinger. I previously used PHP to create APIs retrieving data from the database, where all columns, including IDs, were treated as strings.

**problem:**

After migrating the database using an SQL export/import process, the Flutter app now receives IDs as integers, leading to errors within the app. These errors occur because the Flutter code is expecting string values for IDs, based on the previous behavior.

Why does this data type change occur during migration? and how can I restore back the old behavior ?

[image: API response before migration]

**API response before migration**

[image: API response after migration]

**API response after migration**

Comment: That's not a mysql issue as you receive the data from a php application. Check your php code.

Comment: @Shadow I basically copied and pasted everything as is. I only changed the credentials in the connect.php file.

Comment: Php version could be different. Check your code.

Comment: There's a long way from database column to generated JSON, you need to do some basic debugging to figure out in which step data type gets changed. My educated guess is that your new hosting has a different MySQL driver or different defaults. If you're using PDO, investigate whether `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` and `PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES` make any difference.

Comment: As per [ask], you'd need to provide a [mre] of the issue. We can't fix pictures. Also, please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Code, data and logs are text. Provide it as text, please. Images of text are not searchable, copyable, or re-usable in answers, examples etc. It's a lot harder for people to help you by re-using the data in a test scenario or an answer, and for others with similar issues to find your post. You can [edit] your post. Thanks.